# How to check if someone has admin permission on_message discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a add word to blacklist command and I want to check if the person using the command is a admin. Here are code I tried:

```
if message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server_permissions'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member object has no attribute `server_permissions` but you can use [`message.author.guild_permissions.administrator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions).

Answer (score 0):

try this

`message.author.guild_permissions.administrator`

if this doesn't work try this:
`message.author.top_role.permissions.administrator`

Comment: This works on the commands, not `on_message` event.

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: I am currently testing it